# Javascript & CSS Hamburger menu working in Codepen but not when deployed

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, responsive

I have created a portfolio website and it is now complete. The only thing not working is the menu does not close when a link is clicked, I have added Javascript and tested it in Codepen where is works. When I add it to the GitHub directory it doesn't work on the live site.

[Github Repository](https://github.com/babyblueprojects/personal-portfolio/blob/master/assets/js/menu.js)

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/babyblueprojects/pen/qBZGZeJ)

Below is the working Codepen example:

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector( '#myInput' );
var icon = document.querySelector( '#menuToggle span' );
var listener = function( e ) {
  if( e.target != checkbox && e.target != icon ) {
    checkbox.checked = false;
    document.removeEventListener( 'click', listener );
  }
};

checkbox.addEventListener( 'click', function(){
  if( this.checked ) {
    document.addEventListener( 'click', listener );
  } 
});
```

```css
/* Mobile Menu */
body {
  background: #b0c0c6;
}

#menuToggle {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 1; 
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 6px 4px 1.5px 4px;
}

#menuToggle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #232323;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

#menuToggle a:hover {
  color: tomato;
}


#menuToggle input
{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0; /* hide this */
  z-index: 2; /* and place it over the hamburger */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

#menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 1px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child
{
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

#menuToggle input:checked ~ span
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #13aff0;
}

#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3)
{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

.mobilemenu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: -80px 0 0 -30px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 75px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background: rgb(241,228,219,1);
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;  
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
  position: fixed;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.mobilemenu li
{
  padding: 10px 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 22px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
}

#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul
{
  transform: none;
}

/* Mobile Menu */
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <div id="menuToggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myInput"/>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <ul class="mobilemenu">
      <li><a href="#about" class="active">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#experience">Experience</a></li>
      <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#education">Education</a></li>
      <li><a href="#footer">Contact Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#résumé">Résumé</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Any help or tips appreciated.

Comment: It is true, that your example works here as expected either ?

Comment: The example code you provided is working. I had a look at your HTML file and saw you are linking to quite a few JS files. Are you sure there is not maybe a clash with some code. This code without linking to any other resource is working so that should be a starting point.

Comment: @Brian - I receive this error 

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at menu.js:10"

Comment: @Reporter yes it works above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked over the HTML in your repo. There is one line in there that differs from the codepen you provided.

In line 21 you have `<input type="checkbox" />`, while in the codepen you have `<input type="checkbox" id="myInput"/>`

Your js is trying to add an eventListener to a nonexistent element which is why it is not working.